# My lightbox won't close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, lightbox

I'm trying to make a lightbox following this guide https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_modal.asp and it just won't work.

I'm trying to hide the modal div using this function

```
onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"
```

Are there other similar functions I could use? Im suspecting there is some sort of conflict with the theme I'm using Below is a code-snippet for the lightbox.

Open lightbox (works fine):

```
<div class="product-item grid-item cat-2">
      <div href="#" class="item-image" 
       onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"
       class="w3-button">
```

But closing it is the biggest pain right now... :/

```
       <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
                  <div class="w3-modal-content">
                    <img src="static/products/loelle/05.jpg" alt="06">
                  <span id="hide" 
                  onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'"
                  class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: It works fine for me in [their demo](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal). What have you changed?

Comment: Yeah, this works for me too. Are you getting an error in the console?

Comment: id you include this?: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">`

Comment: I haven't changed anything just added it as, is no console errors. Yes I have included the w3-stylesheet. I'm guessing there is some sort of conflict with one of the plugins im using? Are there other functions for hiding divs?